# Convert column with month and year ("August 2020"...) to datetime

Tags: python, pandas, string, datetime

I have dataframe which contains one column of month and year as string :

```
>>>time           index   value
   January 2021     y        5
   January 2021     v        8
   May 2020         y        25
   June 2020        Y        13
   June 2020        x        11
   June 2020        v        10
...
```

**I would like to change the column "time" into datetime format so I can sort the table by  chronological order.

Is thery any way to do it when the time is string with month name and number?**

#edit:
when I do :

```
result_Table['time']=pd.to_datetime(result_Table['time'],format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

I recieve error:

> ValueError: time data January 2021 doesn't match format specified

Comment: `df['time']=pd.to_datetime(df['time'])`?

Comment: @AnuragDabas I recieve error: ValueError: time data January 2021 doesn't match format specified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample dataframe:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'time':['January 2021','May 2020','June 2020']})
```

If you want to specify the format parameter then that should be `'%B %Y'` instead of `'%Y-%m-%d'`:

```
df['time']=pd.to_datetime(df['time'],format='%B %Y')
#OR
#you can also simply use:
#df['time']=pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
```

output of df:

```
    time
0   2021-01-01
1   2020-05-01
2   2020-06-01
```

For more info regarding format codes [visit here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)